Find records as And in MYSQL
I want find Students id that , must have (professorId = 3 And courseId = 4) And (professorId = 3 And courseId = 2) And (professorId = 5 And courseId = 8).
sometime these parenthesis is one or more than 20
I have two table class and studentsClasses like this :
studentsClasses table:
id | studentId | classId
1        1         2
2        1         3
3        1         4
4        2         3
5        2         5
6        3         2
7        4         3
8        4         2
9        1         8

Class Table:
id | professorId | CourseId

1        1            1
2        3            4
3        2            5
4        3            2
5        4            2
6        2            3
7        5            6
8        5            8
9        5            9

It would be very simple if every parenthesis worked as or. But I want to find a student who has all these things in the form of and.
This query is "OR" scenario:
select `studentsClasses`.`studentId` from `studentsClasses`
 inner join `class` on (`studentsClasses`.`classId`=`class`.`id` 
AND ((professorId = 3 And courseId = 4) OR (professorId = 3 And courseId = 2) 
   OR (professorId = 5 And courseId = 8)))

But i want AND scenario like this:
select `studentsClasses`.`studentId` from `studentsClasses`
     inner join `class` on (`studentsClasses`.`classId`=`class`.`id` 
    AND ((professorId = 3 And courseId = 4) AND (professorId = 3 And courseId = 2) 
       AND (professorId = 5 And courseId = 8)))

But above query is wrong.
For example result query with these value should be :
studentId
---------
1


Can you clarify and show the desired result? Also, you need a generic query or specific one that meets exactly AND ((professorId = 3 And courseId = 4) AND (professorId = 3 And courseId = 2)         AND (professorId = 5 And courseId = 8))) criteria? Not sure what should be the result when you have "sometime these parenthesis is one or more than 20".

These parenthesis can be change   . like when you select filters checkbox @mitkosoft

https://dbfiddle.uk/XrbiAbNh, note the difference if a student attends same class several times.

One way is to use CASE WHEN condition and SUM over it.
SELECT
  studentId,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 4 THEN 1
      WHEN c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 2 THEN 1
      WHEN c.professorId = 5 AND c.courseId = 8 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) AS filter_cnt
FROM studentsClasses s
JOIN class c ON c.id = s.classId
GROUP BY 1
HAVING filter_cnt = 3

Another way is to use a separate join for each condition. Not an efficient solution, but it might be fine if data is not too big.
WITH class_1 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM studentsClasses s
  JOIN class c ON c.id = s.classId AND c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 4
),

class_2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM studentsClasses s
  JOIN class c ON c.id = s.classId AND c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 2
),

class_3 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM studentsClasses s
  JOIN class c ON c.id = s.classId AND c.professorId = 5 AND c.courseId = 8
)

SELECT c1.studentId FROM class_1 c1
JOIN class_2 c2 ON c2.studentId = c1.studentId
JOIN class_3 c3 ON c3.studentId = c1.studentId


Thanks @Kliment Merzlyakov. Unfortunately, if I use this method, due to the large volume of data and also the large number of joins, the data query speed will be slow, perhaps as much as 20 joins.

Yeah, I see. I would give it a try still. I'm not sure if there is a better solution to it. It's a good question, I'll think about it and let you know if anything comes up. Also curious if anybody has a good solution for it.

How many unique combinations of proffesorId and courseId do you have? If it's not huge, then we can try something with pivot tables.

I think about 1000 unique combination . However, please provide this method as well. At least if it is not suitable for me, it will be suitable for other people with less data

Oh, actually the solution with joins doesn't work

Updated, the solution with joins should work now

Okay, @farzad, I came up with another solution — using CASE WHEN. Updated the answer. Could you check it out?

thanks a lot  @Kliment Merzlyakov . You suggested a wonderful method.

Simply do a GROUP BY. Use HAVING to make sure all three professor/course combos are there.
SELECT s.studentId
FROM studentsClasses s
    JOIN class c ON c.id = s.classId
WHERE (c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 4)
   OR (c.professorId = 3 AND c.courseId = 2)
   OR (c.professorId = 5 AND c.courseId = 8)
GROUP BY s.studentId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.courseId) = 3

Thanks to COUNT(DISTINCT c.courseId), this will work even if a student attends same class several times.
Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/XrbiAbNh (scroll to the end).

There are two tables linked by class id, student isn't in the same table as professor/course

Now updated. Join added

One option is to use IN operator on pair of columns, group by student HAVING Count() = Number of pairs listed - 3 in this sample and up to 20 or whatever it is in your actual context...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  studentsClasses ( id, studentId, classId ) AS
    ( Select 1, 1, 2 Union All
      Select 2, 1, 3 Union All
      Select 3, 1, 4 Union All
      Select 4, 2, 3 Union All
      Select 5, 2, 5 Union All
      Select 6, 3, 2 Union All
      Select 7, 4, 3 Union All
      Select 8, 4, 2 Union All
      Select 9, 1, 8
    ),
  Class ( id, professorId, CourseId ) AS
    ( Select 1, 1, 1 Union All
      Select 2, 3, 4 Union All
      Select 3, 2, 5 Union All
      Select 4, 3, 2 Union All
      Select 5, 4, 2 Union All
      Select 6, 2, 3 Union All
      Select 7, 5, 6 Union All
      Select 8, 5, 8 Union All
      Select 9, 5, 9
    ) 

--    S Q L :
Select     s.studentId
From       studentsClasses s
Inner Join Class c ON c.id = s.classId
Where      (c.professorId, c.CourseId) IN( (3, 4), (3, 2), (5, 8) )
Group By   1
Having     Count(s.studentId) = 3  -- 3 is number of pairs matched

/*  R e s u l t :
studentId
---------
        1    */

See the fiddle here.
